# jQuery Mobile and HTML5 Boilerplate

Tags: jquery-mobile, html5boilerplate

Does anybody know of a way to make jQuery Mobile load only on pages with certain screen resolutions? I don't want jQuery Mobile to load if somebody is viewing the page from a desktop/laptop browser because I want to use HTML5 Boilerplate.

For example, if somebody visits my page from their iPhone, I want jQuery Mobile to format the site with the theme I have created, but if they view it from their desktop, I don't want jQuery Mobile to add all the extra tags and stuff.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

var fileref=document.createElement('script')
fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
fileref.setAttribute("src", "js/jqueryMobile.js")   

if (screen.width <= 480) {
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
}
//-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    if (screen.width <= 699) {
    document.location = "mobile/index.html";
    }
    //-->
</script>
```

This piece of script will recognize the screen size, in this case 699 px, and will then tell the server to load a different folder than the root. Just create a folder in on your  server named mobile for your jquery mobile site and thats it. cheers!

Comment: Thanks, David, but wouldn't that mean I would have to manage two separate sites: 1) Mobile, 2) Standard? I'd like to manage just one site, but when the browser width is 480px or below, it loads jQuery Mobile, otherwise I dont' want it to load.

Comment: @user965879 sorry about being new and not knowing how to post. I misunderstood what you wanted to do. i added another answer below that will add a script tag to your header based off the same if statement.

Answer (score 0):

jQM Docs:

- http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/mediahelpers.html

> Note: This feature was deprecated in beta, and removed in 1.0rc1. We
>   recommend using CSS3 Media Queries instead. To support older versions
>   of Internet Explorer, check out [respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond), a fast & lightweight
>   polyfill for min/max-width CSS3 Media Queries.
>
> If you still need this feature, you can find the code here:
>   [jquery.mobile.media.classes.js](https://raw.github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/38d7ad8848f00b0921bf4ae723f3ad199eb851c1/js/jquery.mobile.media.classes.js)